# CiviCRM generates broken link to contribution page

Tags: contribution-page

When I create a new contribution page and use the `links` sub-menu to go to the live location of the page, it redirects to

https://my.site.org/civicrm?page=CiviCRM&q=civicrm/contribute/transact&reset=1&id=1

This link doesn't work however. I can manually fix the url by removing the "civicrm" part, like this:

https://my.site.org/?page=CiviCRM&q=civicrm/contribute/transact&reset=1&id=1

My question is: where does this "civicrm" bit before the question mark come from? What kind of configuration error could cause this problem? I already checked the BASEURL setting, it seems correct (the value is https://my.site.org/)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is the WordPress "base page" setting.  It's at **Administer menu » System Settings » CMS Database Integration**.

That said - I think the way base pages are working in WordPress is slowly being improved over the last couple of versions.  Please let us know what version of CiviCRM you're running; it may be that this is fixed with an upgrade.